# type inference and for expression in scala

Tags: scala, types, type-inference, scala-2.10

This works

```
val keys Option[List[Option[String]]] = someFunctionThatReturnsKeys()
val tries = for (
    unwrapped <- keys) {
        for(keyOption <- unwrapped;
            stripped <- keyOption if stripped.contains(":")) 
        yield Try(java.lang.Long.parseLong(stripped.substring(stripped.lastIndexOf(":") + 1)))         }
```

This does not work.

```
val tries = for (
              unwrapped <- keys;
              keyOption <- unwrapped;
               stripped <- keyOption if stripped.contains(":")) 
            yield Try(java.lang.Long.parseLong(stripped.substring(stripped.lastIndexOf(":") + 1)))
```

The error is for the line

```
keyOption <- unwrapped;
```

The error is displayed as

> type mismatch; found : List[scala.util.Try[Long]] required: Option[?]

I am using eclipse ide with scala 2.10

Why is the type inference failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type inference isn't failing, it's that the `for` desugars into a `flatMap`, and `Option` doesn't know how to flatten anything but another `Option`.

What do you want the return type to be?  That will determine what you actually want to do.  For instance, if you want a list:

```
val tries = for {
  unwrapped <- keys.toList;
  keyOption <- unwrapped;
  stripped <- keyOption if stripped.contains(":")
} yield Try(stripped.substring(1 + stripped.lastIndexOf(":")).toLong)
```

will do the trick.  You'll get a `List[Try[Long]]`, which will be empty if the outer `Option` was `None`.

If you want to keep the outer option, you really want a `map` not a `flatMap` at the outside, which is more easily written like so:

```
val tries2 = keys.map(unwrapped => for {
  keyOption <- unwrapped;
  stripped <- keyOption if stripped.contains(":")
} yield Try(stripped.substring(1 + stripped.lastIndexOf(":")).toLong))
```

This will give you an `Option[List[Try[Long]]]`.